# Two background videos behave differently under the same <video> tag

Tags: html, css, video

I have two videos served online, and two behave differently. 
"Bunny video" sits on top of the nav, and "Space video" is below, under unidentified black background of the nav (which i didn't set).

What might have caused that? I tried it locally and changing the format to  webm  - without success.

```
   <video id="background-video" loop autoplay muted>

      // "bunny video"
     // http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4
      // "space video"
      // http://www.dropbox.com/s/nqkhiatqe9vxw3w/space-odyssey.mp4?raw=1

// I switch those two links here:
      <source src="http://www.dropbox.com/s/nqkhiatqe9vxw3w/space-odyssey.mp4?raw=1" type="video/mp4" />

    </video>
```

Demo on codepen: https://codepen.io/RycerzPegaza/pen/KNYXJg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both videos are behaving the same for me, and both are 1280x720 resolution - however, "Big Buck Bunny" is presented in 16:9 aspect ratio and fills the video frame, whereas the space clip is letterboxed to 16:9 (with black bars baked into the video) because it's presented at a wider aspect ratio.

So, your nav doesn't have a black background - it's actually part of the video. See what I mean?

[image]

Comment: Also the nav is in front of the video in both cases, as should be. The black text just disappears in the black background.